# OpenCV: Merge separated JPEG bayer channels

Tags: opencv, jpeg, channel

I have a camera that is giving 4 separated JPEG images for the 4 different Bayer channels (B,G1,G2,R).

I want to transform this in to a colour image.

What I'm doing at the moment is uncompress the jpeg, restore the "original" image manually and converting to a colour image using cvtColor. But this is too slow. How could I do it better?

```
    cv::Mat imgMat[4]=cv::Mat::zeros(616, 808, CV_8U); //height, width
    for (k=0;k<4;k++) {
        ........
        imgMat[k] = cv::imdecode(buffer, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    }
    //Reconstruct the original image from the four channels! RGGB
    cv::Mat Reconstructed=cv::Mat::zeros(1232, 1616, CV_8U);
    int x,y;
    for(x=0;x<1616;x++){
        for(y=0;y<1232;y++){
            if(y%2==0){
                if(x%2==0){
                    //R
                    Reconstructed.at<uint8_t>(y,x)=imgMat[0].at<uint8_t>(y/2,x/2);
                }
                else{
                    //G1
                    Reconstructed.at<uint8_t>(y,x)=imgMat[1].at<uint8_t>(y/2,floor(x/2));
                }
            }
            else{
                if(x%2==0){
                    //G2
                    Reconstructed.at<uint8_t>(y,x)=imgMat[2].at<uint8_t>(floor(y/2),x/2);
                }
                else{
                    //B
                    Reconstructed.at<uint8_t>(y,x)=imgMat[3].at<uint8_t>(floor(y/2),floor(x/2));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Debayer
    cv::Mat ReconstructedColor;
    cv::cvtColor(Reconstructed, ReconstructedColor, CV_BayerBG2BGR);
```

It seems clear that what it takes more time is decoding the jpeg images. Has somebody some advice/trick I could use to speed up this code?

Comment: Are you sure you cannot set the camera to give as output the raw bayer image, without channel separated and without jpg compression? It might be a problem in term of bandwidth, but for sure it will speed up the subsequent elaboration...

Comment: Yes. I can do that selecting a different mode. But then the frame rate I get is obviously much much slower... I would like to work with higher frame rate.

Comment: I would check where the time is really spent. If it is in the BGGR image reconstruction step, you have some hope. If, on the other end, the time is really spent in imdecode(), I don't see a way in which you can optimize it. If the BGGR image reconstruction step is the part that is taking most of the time in your computation, my first guess is that you have to look into the code of cvtColor and rewrite your own bayer conversion with different kind of input. Also check you are not spending time reallocating memory (all those zeros could be changed with setTo(0). )

Comment: Thanks Antonio. Most of the time spent was in the reconstruction step and I could optimize it with the answer below. It's not yet as fast as I would like, but I don't think I can improve any of the imdecode or dvtColor func. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should do a profile to see where the time is mostly going. Maybe it is all in `imdecode()`, as "seems clear", but you might be wrong.

If not, `.at<>()` is a bit slow (and you are calling it nearly 4 million times). You can get some speedup by more efficent scanning of the image. Also you do not need `floor()` - that will avoid converting an int to double and back again (2 million times). Something like this will be faster:

```
int x , y;
for(y = 0; y < 1232; y++){
    uint8_t* row = Reconstructed.ptr<uint8_t>(y);
    if(y % 2 == 0){
        uint8_t* i0 = imgMat[0].ptr<uint8_t>(y / 2);
        uint8_t* i1 = imgMat[1].ptr<uint8_t>(y / 2);

        for(x = 0; x < 1616; ){
            //R
            row[x] = i0[x / 2];
            x++;

            //G1
            row[x] = i1[x / 2];
            x++;
        }
    }
    else {
        uint8_t* i2 = imgMat[2].ptr<uint8_t>(y / 2);
        uint8_t* i3 = imgMat[3].ptr<uint8_t>(y / 2);

        for(x = 0; x < 1616; ){
            //G2
            row[x] = i2[x / 2];
            x++;

            //B
            row[x] = i3[x / 2];
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was great.

After a more accurate time observation I found out the times for a sample frame were:

Time reading images: 0.008328

Time reconstructing image: 0.041352

Time Debayering: 0.004263

After using you code times were:

Time reading images: 0.008466

Time reconstructing image: 0.008402

Time Debayering: 0.004364

That's 4 times faster reconstructing images, and saves 3 hundredths of second!

I don't think I can get better than that now!